# FFT: zero-padding and mean subtraction

Tags: discrete-data, fourier-transform, spectral-analysis

When computing FFT of a finite-time discrete sample with a non-zero mean, I get two different results depending on the order of operations: whether I zero-pad and then subtract the mean or subtract the mean and zero-pad afterward. What is the right way to go?

As a by-question, I'd be grateful for any reference regarding the practical application of FFT, with a discussion of useful tricks and possible pitfalls.

Comment: If you compute the mean of the zero-padded data, you are (obviously) biasing the mean.  Just a sketch of the answer to "practical application of FFT" would require an encyclopedia -- no kidding.

Comment: Fair enough. I asked because the first procedure (1 zero-pad, 2. subtract the mean) returned a more "regular" picture.  Perhaps it was a sort of by-product of this wrong scheme.